# Tailwind CSS dynamic classes are not rendering correctly

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using NextJs 13.2 with Tailwind 3.3 and I'm trying to create a dynamic Tailwind class, but it is not being applied.

```
export default function Button(props: IButtonProps) {
  const { color = "red", btnTitle, ...restProps } = props;

  const color1 = `bg-${color}-500`;

  const color2 = "bg-red-500";

  return (
    <button className={`py-2 px-4 rounded-sm hover:cursor-pointer shadow-md ${color1}`} {...restProps}>
      <span>{btnTitle}</span>
    </button>
  );
}
```

When I pass color1 background color is not changing but when I pass color2 it does work as expected.